# Dynamically generate array of objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm adapting a D3 pie chart to my own work and want to dynamically recreate the data structure seen below.

```
    var data = [
{"label":"Colorectale levermetastase (n=336)", "value":74}, 
{"label": "Primaire maligne levertumor (n=56)", "value":12},
{"label":"Levensmetatase van andere origine (n=32)", "value":7}, 
{"label":"Beningne levertumor (n=34)", "value":7}];
```

I've tried

```
data += {"label": cat_row, "value": +freq_row};
```

but it doesn't give the desired results. Also pushing does nothing.

```
data["label"] = cat_row;
```

The line above just seems to overwrite the each iteration.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Also pushing does nothing" can you show what you're trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to dynamically recreate the data structure.

To add a new element to the end of the array:

```
 data.push({"label": cat_row, "value": +freq_row});
```

or

```
data[data.length] = {"label": cat_row, "value": +freq_row};
```

To add a new element to the beginning of the array:

```
data.unshift({"label": cat_row, "value": +freq_row}));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also pushing does nothing.

You are almost there, need to push this way

```
var data = [];
data.push( {"label": cat_row, "value": freq_row } );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array you need to use `Array#push()`. This will add the element in parameter to the end of the array

```
var data = [];
data.push({label:"test"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to add data to your array or do you want to replace the data?

to add data to the array use:

```
data.push({"label": cat_row, "value": +freq_row})
```

to replace data in your array:

```
var index = 0;
data[index] = {"label": cat_row, "value": +freq_row};
```